# oracle sql counts

Tags: sql, oracle, count

If `portfolio id` has the stock code using the count.
 
example `Portfolio id 500` has `stock_code 'IBM'` It count one `Portfolio id 500` has `stock_code 'GBA'` it counts two

If input `Portfolio id 500` and `stock_code 'ABC'` It count 0 
not raising an error message because of the `stock_code` is exist.

```
Portfolio id   stock_code
    500            IBM
    500            GBA
    500            GBA


select count(distinct stock_code,portfolio_number)
into V_count 
from Stock 
where P_Stock_Code = stock_code
and P_Portfolio_number=portfolio_number;
```

showing error

> invalid number of arguments

pass two INPUT parameters

or maybe I can not verify  the id own or not own the `stock_code` using count??

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to achieve. Please describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: if I pass two input parameters
select PKG_Q4.FN_Q4('500','vf') from dual; it will count 0 because the id number 500 had not stock code 'vf'

Comment: if i   select PKG_Q4.FN_Q4('500','GBA') from dual;  it will count 2 because  the id number 500 has 2 different 'GBA' with different time

Comment: Ok. So what do you want to do ? You want to pass only one parameter ? Do you want to count all stock_code seperately? Or when you pass a parameter that does not exist, you want to see count not zero but null ?

Comment: I am doing an if else.  if count = 0  then .... if count >=1 then ...

Comment: I need to pass two-parameter.  to verify the id own or not own the stock code

Answer (score 0):

As you can already understand you can not pass two parameters to `COUNT` function. But You can do something like below instead.

```
WITH STOCK
     AS (SELECT 500 PORTFOLIO_ID, 'IBM' AS STOCK_CODE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 500 PORTFOLIO_ID, 'GBA' AS STOCK_CODE FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 500 PORTFOLIO_ID, 'GBA' AS STOCK_CODE FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE WHEN CNT = 0 THEN 'CASE1' WHEN CNT >= 1 THEN 'CASE2' END KEYZ
  FROM (  SELECT STOCK_CODE, COUNT (PORTFOLIO_ID) AS CNT
            FROM STOCK
        GROUP BY STOCK_CODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just trying to check if Passed `P_Portfolio_number` has how many distinct `P_Stock_Code`.

You can use the following:

```
select count(distinct stock_code)
  into V_count -- 0,1,2 .. you can use it wherever you want then
  from Stock 
 where P_Stock_Code = stock_code
   and P_Portfolio_number=portfolio_number;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
select count(1)
      into V_count
      from (select distinct stock_code, portfolio_number
              from Stock
             where P_Stock_Code = stock_code
               and P_Portfolio_number = portfolio_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support a list of columns in `COUNT DISTINCT`. I wrote an according request in Oracle's database ideas portal more than two years ago: https://community.oracle.com/ideas/18664. You can register and then upvote this idea. I think, however, that for the given situation you don't need it.

Just use `COUNT(*)`. The following counts the rows for a given combination of stock code and portfolio number (1 for 500|IBM, 2 for 500|GBA, 0 for 500|ABC).

### In PL/SQL:

```
create or replace procedure myproc(p_stock_code varchar2, p_portfolio_number integer) as
  v_count  integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  into v_count 
  from stock 
  where stock_code = p_stock_code
  and portfolio_number = p_portfolio_number;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
end myproc;
```

### In SQL:

```
select count(*)
from stock 
where stock_code = :p_stock_code
and portfolio_number = :p_portfolio_number;
```